# The difference between semicontinuity and hemicontinuity.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, functions, continuity

For a point-to-set function F, is "upper hemicontinuous" the same as "upper semicontinuous"?

If not, then what's the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Hemicontinuity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemicontinuity) and [semi-continuity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity) differ in the sense that the latter is a property of functions in particular, whereas the former belongs to [correspondences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_%28mathematics%29) or [relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation) in general. Functions are basically correspondences which assign a single value to any given element, whereas relations do not necessarily abide by this restriction.

Comment: Thanks for answering, the concept is clearer now.